# Having trouble with HTML5 audio on Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox, ogg

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read my question.

I'm building an application where I am integrating HTML5 audio with jQuery. On Chrome, it plays! On Firefox, it doesn't..

I have both .mp3 and .ogg files and have writted the audio tag as follows:

```
<audio id="drop-sound">
    <source src="music/water-droplet-1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    <source src="music/water-droplet-1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

My jQuery then plays this as follows:

```
//drop sound
var audioDrop = $('#drop-sound')[0];

//play drop
audioDrop.play();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few ideas that might help you fix the problem.

The first one is to change the audio tag to look like this.

```
<audio id="drop-sound">
  <source src="music/water-droplet-1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="music/water-droplet-1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Use type `audio/mpeg` instead of `audio/mp3`

The second is to change the javascript to be

```
document.getElementById('drop-sound').play();
```

This is faster then setting a variable and then telling it to play.

The last thing is to check that your server is sending the correct MIME types. Here is a [tutorial](http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/) explaining this.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried my best to implement it correctly but I couldn't get it to work. Instead of .ogg I've now used .wav and it works fine.